# Adding code specific to Windows Phone Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, windows-phone-8

I've been testing out the Google Maps API on various browsers and also different phones/tablets... all is working fine except for when trying it on a Windows Phone. After some research I've found out it's because Google Maps isn't supported on Windows Phones hence the error.

My question is how would I go about making it so that it displays an image of the map instead of the map API?

eg. for Windows Phone it would display:

```html
<div><img src="map.png"></div>
```

But for everything else it would display and use the API:

```html
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the user agent for *IEMobile*

This is the windows phone mobile agent.

Or better yet can you not do a boolean check if the map is working so if it fails in any browser then you are covered?

Comment: Thanks... that's essentially what I ended up doing using PHP.

`return strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'IEMobile');`